# TeX.SE around the world

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this is the place to ask so, sorry if I'm wrong.

I was asking myself about the distribution of TeX.SE users around the world. Is it possible to have a kind of map to see from where the users come from? Something similar to [ClustrMaps](http://clustrmaps.com/pt/index.htm)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There was a blog post about this in 2011: http://tex.blogoverflow.com/2011/10/tex-sx-users-around-the-world/

Back then, I also created a zoomable flash map of the users locations: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3113270/TeX-SX-users.swf

[image]

Comment: Sadly, there are only a few users from my country. Well, TeX and friends are almost not used here and scarcely even in the academe except for journal submissions. `:-(`

Comment: 21 from Torontoo and 9 from Waterloo? We should have a meetup at a local pub!

Comment: @Canageek: I'll be in Waterloo for a couple of months starting in April! Let me know which pub you're meeting at

Comment: Woolrich arms. Let me know when you will be here and I'll make a meta post about meeting up.